# Qualitatively analyzing the local behavior of equilibria

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the system

$$r' = r-r^3$$ $$\theta' = \sin(\theta)^2-\frac{1}{4}$$

I know the equilibria are $$(0,0) \space (1,\frac{\pi}{6}) \space (1,-\frac{\pi}{6}) \space (1, \frac{5\pi}{6}) \space (1, -\frac{5\pi}{6})$$

but I do not know how to analyze the local behavior of each one without using the hartman-grobman theorem. I want to be able to figure out if each one is a source or a sink, straight line solutions, spirals, centers, etc. All with minimal computation. Also try to try to draw the whole phase portrait using qualitative methods (I know this is possible because I saw a professor do it in thirty seconds in his head, writing on a blackboard. He did not, however, explain his thinking).  Any help is appreciated. If you give me hints that lead me to the answer , I will accept and post my solution in the question.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the Hartman-Grobman theorem? Your system is not difficult to linearize. (Maybe it doesn't apply here, I haven't checked).

Comment: @Olivier Because changing to Cartesian coordinates and applying hartman-grobman  makes the algebra hellish, and it does't work at $(0,0)$, since the jacobian is not defined.

Comment: Can't you apply Hartman-Grobman in polar coordinates, at least around points such that $r > 0$?

Comment: How would I do that? Whenever my professor uses it, he transforms the system to cartesian, since otherwise we can't find the linearized system. Is there a general hartman-grobman theorem that avoids explicit use of the jacobian that I could use, or is there some way to find the values of the jacobian without doing a coordinate transfromation?

Comment: You can calculate the jacobian of $f(r,\theta) = (r-r^3, \sin(\theta)^2 - \mu)$. Try to figure out how the jacobian of $f$ relates to the jacobian of the cartesian system (using the change of coordinates diffeomorphism). You should find that they are conjugate.

Comment: A diffeomorphism is just a change of coordinates (bijective transform that is smooth and that has a smooth inverse).

Comment: 1. Your equilibria are incorrect; the angular part should depend on $\mu$.
2. The Hartman-Grobman theorem still applies, especially for those equilibria where $r>0$.
3. The origin is clearly a source; the radial component will increase when $r>0$ is small because of the linear term.

Comment: Yes, they are incorrect. $/mu$ should be 1/4. Also, the origin may be a source, but is it a spiral, does it have straightline solutions, etc. These are the questions I don't know how to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you an engineering answer.

I assume that $r\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\theta \in [-\pi, \pi]$. We know that:
$$r=0 \Leftrightarrow r\in \{-1, 0, 1\}$$
$$\theta = 0 \Leftrightarrow \theta\in \{-5\pi/6, -\pi/6, \pi/6, 5\pi/6\}$$
Therefore, the equilibrium points are indicated in the figure of Step 1, where the horizontal and vertical axis represent $r$ and $\theta$, respectively.

By looking to the sign of the derivatives of $r$ and $\theta$ at each region, we can indicate the direction of their change. Look at to step 1.
[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjk8b.png)

Now we can roughly indicate the phase portrait. (Step 2)
[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HupKY.png)

Now we can verify that the points 1, 3, 7, and 9 are stable equilibriums (or sinks), and the other points, i.e., 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, and 12 are unstable equilibriums (or sources).